# Visual Studio Unable to Add Data Connection to SQL Server Express 2016

Tags: sql-server, data-connections, visual-studio-community, sql-server-2016-express

I'm working in VisualStudio Community 2015, SQL SERVER EXPRESS 2016 and when I try to add server connection with sqlServer appears the error I attach below:

[image]

(After TEST the connection and be safe that all is right)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc, Version=12.0.0.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41313649/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-sqlserver-management-sdk-sfc-version)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed... I had to install SQL Server 2014 :(

Answer (score 0):

**It is not necessary to install sql server 2014**

Only you have to install sql server 2014 feature pack because it contains assemblies needed by visual studio 2015

**Download link**

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42295

Answer (score 0):

This is the new problem I have in VS 2022 it works fine in VS 2019

The same, issue is happening with Visual Studio 2022. It works fine with VS 2019.

The connections/ login window looks like in SQL Server Management Studio.

Details: in Visual Studio on the SQL Server Object Explorer I was able to add the PDW server.

I can browse the server tables, stored procedures, security and all.

If I right-click on a database, or table and select "New Query", it will ask me to log in with the same window as M Studio.

I am able to connect fine if I open an existing query.DSQL file it allows me to use history connections or connect normally.

So I am connected to the server on SQL Server Object Explorer but when try to open a stored procedure it asks to login again and that is where it fails because it tries to connect with different parameters

[image]

[image]