# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc, Version=12.0.0.0

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015

I'm running Visual Studio community 2015 with Sql Server 2012 Express.

When I try to view my database tables I receive the following [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynlR4.png)

I have manually installed LocalDb and Management Objects to no avail and this is the only advice i've been able to source.

What I dont understand is why I am receiving an error message about management objects when I have installed it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hey dude look at this it might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906686/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-sqlserver-management-sdk-sfc-version-1

Comment: Hi Valkyriee, I've already used these links and sadly they didnt help. I downloaded the 2012 shared management objects one and it didnt help. I've also tried 2014 and unsurprisingly it didnt work as im not using sql 2014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to download SQL Server shared management objects 2014 found in SQL server 2014 feature pack. Visual Studio 2015 need sql server 2014 assemblies even if other versions are installed.

**Download Link below**

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42295

Comment: Hi Hadi, thanks for the reply.

I have tried to download 2014 Shared management objects and it wont let me as im missing an installation prerequisite:
Microsoft SQL server 2014 System CLR Types.

I'm not using SQL 2014 and i have already downloaded Shared Management Objects for Sql 2012...

Comment: Feature pack contains clr types package

Comment: Visual studio 2015 need sql server 2014 feature pack . Even if you installed sql server 2012 MO

Comment: Hadi, you're a hero. All sorted now, thanks for your help.